# Paypal Invoice after Payment

Tags: php, paypal

I'm a slight bit confused about the Paypal API. I'm using Paypal Payments to have a customer pay on the spot with the PHP SDK.

```
        $apiContext = new ApiContext(
            new OAuthTokenCredential(
                $this->paypalid,
                $this->paypalsecret
            )
        );

        $payer = $_GET['payerId'];
        $paymentid = $_GET['paymentId'];

        $payment = Payment::get($paymentid, $apiContext);

        $transaction = $payment->getTransactions();

        $execution = new PaymentExecution();
        $execution->setPayerId($payer)
                ->setTransactions($transaction);

        try{
            $result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo "Couldn't process payment";
            exit;
        }
```

I would like to generate an invoice based on the payment done for tax reasons. Currently all this does is send a notification to both the seller/buyer concerning the transaction being successful. Paypal's API seems to heavily imply that invoices are used to process payments, which in this case, the payment is already done; I don't want the customer to pay twice.

I imagine that I need to set the status property on an Invoice object to "PAID" and set the amount paid equal to the total amount present on the payment, and then use the send method along with the apiContext.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Dear @sefam, I'm having the exact problem as you. Did you find a solution for this? I thought I could use the Invoice API for the same purpose, but it is just generating a Payment promt, I just want to generate the invoice and mark it as paid. I'm stuck.

Comment: As far as I understand, I have to create an invoice, send it via email and mark it as PAID afterwards. This will lead into bad user experience. First, an email with a payment prompt (user already paid), a second email that will "thank for the payment". If the user clicks the "PAY" Button now will lead into "already paid" message. Thats such a big bummer..